# Not able to pass JTable to Jasper report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, jtable, report

```
private void txtPrintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("../report/report2.jrxml");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport("../report/report2.jasper",new HashMap(),new JRTableModelDataSource(tblStock.getModel()));
    JasperViewer jasperviewer=new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
    jasperviewer.setVisible(true);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception in generating report,generateReport() of JasperReportGenerator:"+e);
}
}
```

Jasper Report which is generated with this code, does not show the contents of JTable (tblStock)..it just shows two bold empty heading lines on the report..anybody help..

Comment: Where is the JTable in your code? Are you using a JTable as the model for a report?

Comment: You can look at [TableModel Data Source sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#tablemodeldatasource) and [Fill a report with JRTableModelDataSource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/node/508028) post

Comment: jtable is tblstock(jtable's variable name) and it is present int same java file..jtable is populated with data from database..i hav already referred to these links..but could not find the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Please, check font size and/or height of each element in the table body cell. Also you have to check template - elements can't overlap.

Comment: jtable is tblstock(jtable's variable name) and it is present int same java file..jtable is populated with data from database..i hav already referred to these links..but could not find the solution..